Line by line alternative to a for loop that references previous row
I am working with some data and I would like to create a column for which the next row value depends on that of the previous row. A for loop was my first thought for this, but the data I am working with is over 6 million rows, and the for loop took over 1 hour to complete.
I am looking for an alternative to a for loop that would accomplish this. The data is formatted in such a way that I don't believe the dplyr lag() would accomplish what I need. Say I have the following data:
df = structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), y = c(0, 
1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), z = c(5, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, 
3, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))


When df$y is not NA, I would like a new column, df$aa to simply return the value in df$z. In cases where df$y does is NA, I want column df$aa to simply be the last non NA value.
Here is the for loop I developed. It works fine with small amounts of data, but as mentioned, it was far too slow with 6 million rows.
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(!is.na(df$z[i])){
    df$aa[i] = df$z[i] 
  } else{
    df$aa[i] = df$aa[i-1]
  } 
}


This code presents the desired output. Your input is greatly appreciated!
EDIT: I prefer a solution that works well with dplyr because the calculation will be done on a per group basis using dplyr::group_by()

When you say "When df$y is not NA" and "where df$y does is NA", you mean df$z, right?

On dplyr, just create your column and fill it down:
new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(aa = z) %>% 
  fill(aa, .direction = "down")

Output:
> new_df
    x y  z aa
1   1 0  5  5
2   2 1 NA  5
3   3 2 NA  5
4   4 3 NA  5
5   5 0  6  6
6   6 1 NA  6
7   7 2 NA  6
8   8 3 NA  6
9   9 4  3  3
10 10 5  2  2


This should be much quicker. Essentially the logic is if z is NA, we use the last non-NA value of z, which we access with data.table::nafill(). If z is not NA then aa <- z. When put like that, I realise this is the same logic as nafill(), so it doesn't even need an ifelse().
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, aa := nafill(z, type = "locf")]


#         x     y     z    aa
#     <num> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:     1     0     5     5
#  2:     2     1    NA     5
#  3:     3     2    NA     5
#  4:     4     3    NA     5
#  5:     5     0     6     6
#  6:     6     1    NA     6
#  7:     7     2    NA     6
#  8:     8     3    NA     6
#  9:     9     4     3     3
# 10:    10     5     2     2

Filling by group
I see you have edited your question to say you want to do this by group. I am not clear which column is the grouping one, but assuming it is y, you can do:
df[, aa := nafill(z, type = "locf"), y]

The essential point is that grouping in data.table is as easy as in dplyr. The syntax is:
DT[i, j, by]

See the vignettes for more.

Not super fast but short and should definitely be faster than your solution
df = structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                    y = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                    z = c(5, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2)), 
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))


df$aa <- zoo::na.locf(df$z)


Another data.table approach that instead uses setnafill:
library(data.table)

setnafill(setDT(df)[is.na(y) == FALSE, aa := z], "locf", cols = "aa")[]
#>         x     y     z    aa
#>     <num> <num> <num> <num>
#>  1:     1     0     5     5
#>  2:     2     1    NA     5
#>  3:     3     2    NA     5
#>  4:     4     3    NA     5
#>  5:     5     0     6     6
#>  6:     6     1    NA     6
#>  7:     7     2    NA     6
#>  8:     8     3    NA     6
#>  9:     9     4     3     3
#> 10:    10     5     2     2

